# Target variable for a supervised learning approach for market sentiment index

Tags: machine-learning, financial-markets

My goal is to produce a signal going from -1 (negative) to +1 (positive) which corresponds to a sentiment index for USA.

The index will be computed both based on headlines (taken from some free resources like FinViz), and twitter, and numerical data (economic indicator are likely linked to sentiment).

It will not be a sentiment on a stock but instead on a geografic area.

The problem is that for my training step I need the "answer".
I would need, for the past, a resources which tells me which was the us sentiment from, say, 60s onwards. Clearly I would also need the headlines (input), for the same period.

It is a 3-class classification problem (3 classes: -1, 0, +1), which could probably be simplified as binary (-1, +1) removing the neutral sentiment.

Does anybody know any resource for such past sentiment data? Does this approach seem a good one?
To avoid, struggling with the target variable, do you suggest an unsupervised approach? if yes, which one?

Comment: As I understand it, _sentiment_ is commonly extracted from news, e.g. by looking for the existence of specific words or sentences. Else, you could go for something like the Purchase Managers Index or such? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchasing_Managers%27_Index

Comment: Thanks, indeed portion of the input is made of news. However, it is evident that some market indicators are correlated to the sentiment, like recession (during recession typically the sentiment is negative). So I would combine both type of data. Its my idea, but can be wrong. My target variable is a sentiment as expressed by a number that can be normilised between -1 and 1, so in the end I would call this "sentiment" even if there are not only news or social media data. Anyway I am still in the process of defining the problem and the best solution so I change the approach based on suggestions.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: If you take as input the sentiment that somebody else has **computed**, you might be re-implementing their sentiment algorithm with ML.. That would be odd, no?

Comment: mm not sure if I got you but the point is the prediction, so whenever you implement supervised learning you need labels of past data in order to fine the sensitivities of the model you chose which will after classify a new tweet as positive or negative. Probably I should label myself the training set, or make them labelled by colleagues (and then average them out) to reduce bias..after I may use SVC to train the model and classify new incoming tweets or news..